# Can I access by property names in Velocity?

Tags: java, properties, velocity, getter

I got an example

```
#set($organizationId = $layout.getGroup().getOrganizationId())
```

can I rewrite it as

```
#set($organizationId = $layout.group.organizationId)
```

?

Will it be exactly the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. See here: [Velocity User Guide - Property Lookup Rules](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/user-guide.html#property-lookup-rules) which states:

As an example, `$customer.address`, the sequence is

1. `getaddress()`
2. `getAddress()`
3. `get("address")`
4. `isAddress()`

To be more precise, [Velocity User Guide - Case Substitution](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/user-guide.html#case-substitution):

```
$data.getRequest().getServerName()
## is the same as
$data.Request.ServerName
```

Comment: But writing getter call with parentheses is also correct and means what is seems to mean, right?